# D3.js clip paths cut off the edge of my graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have set up a clip path on a D3.js zoomable focus and context graph, but have a slight problem. http://nestoria.darkgreener.com/v2/

The clip path is cutting off some circles from the edge of the focus graph - you'll see that the top and right-hand circles are only half there!

It works well on zoom, though, as you'll see if you click and drag the context graph.

So I'm not sure how to create a clip path that doesn't cut off the edges of these circles. This is my code:

```
focus.append("defs")
  .append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width - 200)
  .attr("height", height);
var focus_dots = focus
  .selectAll(".dot")
  .data(mydata[j].data);
focus_dots.enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
```

Any ideas? Your help would be very much appreciated as I'm completely baffled about what to do here!

Comment: Do you mean that they are only cut off on hover? That's how it appears so me on Chrome.

Comment: If you don't want the circles to be clipped, don't apply the clip-path to them (or their parent element)?

Comment: @Duopixel - yes, sorry, they are clipped on hover.

Comment: @ErikDahlström - thanks, but the clip path is necessary, as otherwise when the user changes the brush on the context graph, the lines all shoot off beyond the boundaries of the graph.

Comment: @Richard - how about a simple CSS stylerule for when the circles are hovered then, `circle:hover { clip-path: none; }`?

Comment: @ErikDahlström - that works perfectly! Thank you very much. If you'd like to submit it as an answer then I will accept.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the clipping to not be applied when hovering you can use a stylerule like this:

`circle:hover { clip-path: none; }`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and got around it using

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0,-20)")
.attr("height", height+20)
```

The Idea is a bit hacky, but if you simply move the clipping window up and add the same amount to its height, it should show (in the above case) 20px more on top. (same for left side; concerning the right and bottom side: simply add some pixels to hight/width).

Answer (score 0):

I've used "transform",and the circles were cut to quarter.So use cx and cy instead, problem solved..